# Email Confirmation with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am wondering how can i ask the user to prompt with a field for a confirmation input box with devise in the registration. I have try email_confirmation but it doesn't work any other way around it? with devise

Update:

I want to add a field confirm_email: when a user register on my site with devise

So on the form: `users/sign_up`

I would like something has follow

```
Name:
Email:
Email_Confirmation:
Password:
Password_Confirmation:
```

I do not know how to to make an email_confirmation field!

Comment: sorry, can you please re-edit your question to make it more clear ?

Comment: I will update and see if possible!